# Drag vertices without pulling other faces

Tags: modeling, vertices

[image]So I have subdivided a face on a cube 9 times and I want to pull a certain area of the face backwards into the cube to make eyes. However, when I select certain vertices and bring them back, they pull the faces surrounding them back as well so they are slanted. Is there a way to only bring the faces that I selected back, so new faces are created on the side?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It sounds like you're pressing g and then dragging the selected vertices. Instead, Press e to extrude new vertices from the selected points, and then drag. That will create the faces you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like what you need is the *Extrude* tool. Key <kbd>E</kbd> and then either drag an arrow or key <kbd>X</kbd> (in your case) for the *X-axis* and drag or type in a value.